# Understanding иметь ввиду

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

I read that the translation of "what do you mean?" is **что вы имеете ввиду?**

1) Which is the correct or better form: **ввиду** or **в виду**? Or there is no difference?

2) What is the literal translation of **иметь ввиду**?

I know **иметь** means "to have", and according to Wiktionary **ввиду** means "in view of", so my rough guess is that the literal translation of **иметь ввиду** is "to have a view", and the literal translation of **что вы имеете ввиду?** is "what view do you have?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the idiom "*Иметь в виду*" only split writing is acceptable. It literally means, as you guess, *to have in a view*, but really stands for *to mean*.

Yet there also exists the preposition *ввиду* (obviously made of the split form *в виду* - it's quite a common thing in Russian), which means *due to*, *because of*. Actually you can compose some meaningful sentence using *иметь* and *ввиду*, but probably it wouldn't be what *Вы имели в виду*.

Answer (score 8):

`Иметь ввиду` is a grammar mistake. The right way of writing is `Иметь в виду`. It is an idiom meaning `to mean` or `to keep in mind`.

```
Что ты имеешь в виду?
What do you mean?

Имей в виду, что они не согласятся с тобой.
Keep in mind that they won't agree with you.
```